# Create a histogram from a given list of integers

Tags: python

```
def histrogram(nums):
    for x in nums:
        output = ''
        while x > 0:
            output = output + "x"
            x = x - 1
        print(output)

histrogram([2, 3, 6, 5])
```

What does `x = x - 1` do when you run the program?

Comment: It sets the value of `x` to the previous value of `x` minus `1`.

Comment: x = 2, 3, 6, 5  so whats the point of deducting 1 from x?

Comment: To decrement it, so you print as many `"x"`s as the value of `x`. It seems pointless, you could just `for x in nums: print("x" * x)`.

Comment: okay i kinda get it. thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

The `histrogram` function loops through a list of numbers (`nums`) in order:

```
for x in nums
```

With each number in the list it creates a string (`output`) containing "x". It then subtracts one from the number `x = x - 1`, and joins another "x" to the `output` string. This continues until the number reaches a value of 1 when the loop is finished and the number gets printed.

So `histrogram([2, 3, 6, 5])` would produce:

```
xx
xxx
xxxxxx
xxxxx
```